# zf2 navigation, how to hide some items based on session

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

My zendframwork 2 application contains a navigation in my application/module.php , this navigation contains many items from which some of them are ( login - logout - register )

I don't need to show the three all the time In the navigation menu.. when the user is n't logged in I must show him : login- register , after he logs-in, I must show him only logout link

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you use ACL in your project?

Comment: Till now no,
Will it have effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Removing pages](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.navigation.containers.html#removing-pages)

Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{               
    $application = $e->getApplication();
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
    if (user not login) {
        $container = $serviceManager ->get('navigation');
        $logoutPage = $container->findBy('route' , 'logout');
        $container->removePage($logoutPage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["login"]) { ?>

    <a href="#">Logout</a>

<?php } else { ?>

    <a href="#">Login</a>
    <a href="#">Register</a>

<?php } ?>
```

or something similar to this might work. Replace the "login" key with whatever yours is.

Comment: I'm using zend framework 2 navigation component :
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.navigation.quick-start.html
Not writing plain links

Comment: @Zack This is not a right answer at all, it's obviously need to use Zend component and no plain PHP.